# Cannot create ActiveMQ queue or send a message using java

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I'm new to ActiveMQ. I'm running the ActiveMQ server on windows using the default settings on the local machine. I've tried to create a simple queue to test sending a message.

```
public class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Foo().send();
    }

    public void send(){    
        try {
            ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost:61616");
            Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
            connection.start();

            Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            Destination destination = session.createQueue("TESTQUEUE");
            MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
            producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);

            TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("MESSAGE123");
            producer.send(message);

            session.close();
            connection.close();

        } catch (JMSException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Foo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }    
}
```

This code doesn't seem to do anything when I try to check it by logging on to ActiveMQ admin page and check the queue. (localhost:8161/admin/queues.jsp)
The queue is not created. Then tried creating a queue manually from the admin page and the message is not sent to the queue even though the queue is created.

When I test the server using the commands `activemq producer` and `activemq consumer` the queue is created and the messages are passed to the queue and read from the queue. So I'm certain that there is nothing wrong with the server.

When I run the code this is the terminal output

```
WARN | Memory Usage for the Broker (1024mb) is more than the maximum available for the JVM: 887 mb - resetting to 70% of maximum available: 621 mb
 INFO | Using Persistence Adapter: KahaDBPersistenceAdapter[C:\Users\Prashan\Desktop\Test\activemq-data\localhost\KahaDB]
 INFO | JMX consoles can connect to service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi
 INFO | KahaDB is version 6
 INFO | Recovering from the journal @1:3712
 INFO | Recovery replayed 1 operations from the journal in 0.01 seconds.
 INFO | PListStore:[C:\Users\Prashan\Desktop\Test\activemq-data\localhost\tmp_storage] started
 INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.13.2 (localhost, ID:CAPSULE-5179-1461559222267-0:1) is starting
 INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.13.2 (localhost, ID:CAPSULE-5179-1461559222267-0:1) started
 INFO | For help or more information please see: http://activemq.apache.org
 WARN | Store limit is 102400 mb (current store usage is 0 mb). The data directory: C:\Users\Prashan\Desktop\Test\activemq-data\localhost\KahaDB only has 6947 mb of usable space. - resetting to maximum available disk space: 6947 mb
 WARN | Temporary Store limit is 51200 mb (current store usage is 0 mb). The data directory: C:\Users\Prashan\Desktop\Test\activemq-data\localhost\tmp_storage only has 6947 mb of usable space. - resetting to maximum available disk space: 6947 mb
 INFO | Connector vm://localhost started
 INFO | Connector vm://localhost stopped
 INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.13.2 (localhost, ID:CAPSULE-5179-1461559222267-0:1) is shutting down
 INFO | PListStore:[C:\Users\Prashan\Desktop\Test\activemq-data\localhost\tmp_storage] stopped
 INFO | Stopping async queue tasks
 INFO | Stopping async topic tasks
 INFO | Stopped KahaDB
 INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.13.2 (localhost, ID:CAPSULE-5179-1461559222267-0:1) uptime 1.918 seconds
 INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.13.2 (localhost, ID:CAPSULE-5179-1461559222267-0:1) is shutdown
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are actually creating an embedded broker and the message is sent there. You should connect to your local machine broker by: `tcp://localhost:61616"` rather than `vm://...`.